# Saving image from Gallery to db - Coursor IllegalStateException

Tags: android, image, listview, android-sqlite

I want to save to db some strings with image. Image can be taken from gallery or user can set the sample one. In the other activity I have a listview which should present the rows with image and name. I'm facing so long this problem. It occurs when I wanna display listview with the image from gallery, If the sample image is saved in the row everything works ok.  My problem is similar to this one: [how to save image taken from camera and show it to listview - crashes with "IllegalStateException"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15954896/how-to-save-image-taken-from-camera-and-show-it-to-listview-crashes-with-ille)  but I can't find there the solution for me

My table in db looks like this:

```
public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String ID_DETAILS = "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT";
public static final int ID_COLUMN = 0;

public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String NAME_DETAILS = "TEXT NOT NULL";
public static final int NAME_COLUMN = 1;

public static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";
public static final String DESCRIPTION_DETAILS = "TEXT";
public static final int DESCRIPTION_COLUMN = 2;

public static final String KEY_IMAGE ="image" ; 
public static final String IMAGE_DETAILS = "BLOB";
public static final int IMAGE_COLUMN = 3;

//method which create our table 
private static final String CREATE_PRODUCTLIST_IN_DB = 
        "CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLE + "( " 
        + KEY_ID + " " + ID_DETAILS + ", " 
        + KEY_NAME + " " + NAME_DETAILS + ", "
        + KEY_DESCRIPTION + " " + DESCRIPTION_DETAILS + ", "
        + KEY_IMAGE +" " + IMAGE_DETAILS + ");";
```

inserting statement:

```
public long insertToProductList(String name, String description, byte[] image)
{
    ContentValues value = new ContentValues();
    // get the id of column and value 
    value.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    value.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, description);
    value.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);
    // put into db 
    return db.insert(DB_TABLE, null, value);
}
```

Button which add the picture and onActivityResult method which saves the image and put it into the imageview

```
public void AddPicture(View v)
{   
    // creating specified intent which have to get data 


    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    // From where we want choose our pictures 
    intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if identification code match to the intent, 
    //if yes we know that is our picture,
    if(requestCode ==PICK_IMAGE )
    {
        // check if the data comes with intent 
        if(data!= null)
        {
            Uri chosenImage =  data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(chosenImage,      filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePat = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            ImageOfProduct = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePat);
            if(ImageOfProduct!=null)
            {                   
                picture.setImageBitmap(ImageOfProduct);
            }               
            messageDisplayer("got picture, isn't null " + IdOfPicture);
        }           
    }
}
```

Then the code which converts bitmap to byte[]

```
    public byte[] bitmapToByteConvert(Bitmap bit )
{
    // stream of data getted for compressed bitmap
    ByteArrayOutputStream gettedData = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    // compressing method 
    bit.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, gettedData);
    // our byte array 
    return gettedData.toByteArray();
}
```

The method which put data to the row:

```
    byte[] image=null;
    // if the name isn't put to the editView
    if(name.getText().toString().trim().length()== 0)
    {
        messageDisplayer("At least you need to type name of product if you want add it to the DB ");
    }
    else{
        String desc = description.getText().toString();
        if(description.getText().toString().trim().length()==0)
        {
            messageDisplayer("the description is set as none");
            desc = "none";
        } 
    DB.open();
       if(ImageOfProduct!= null){
    image = bitmapToByteConvert(ImageOfProduct);
    messageDisplayer("image isn't null");
    }
    else
    {
        BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) picture.getDrawable();
        image = bitmapToByteConvert(drawable.getBitmap());
    }
    if(image.length>0 && image!=null)
    {
        messageDisplayer(Integer.toString(image.length));
    }
    DB.insertToProductList(name.getText().toString(), desc, image );
    DB.close();
   messageDisplayer("well done you add the product");
    finish();
```

You can see that I'm checking here the length of array to be sure that I don't send empty one.

And here is the place where Error appears imo, this code is from activity which presents the listview with data taken from db

```
private void LoadOurLayoutListWithInfo() 
 {
     // firstly wee need to open connection with db 

     db= new sqliteDB(getApplicationContext());
     db.open();

      // creating our custom adaprer, the specification of it will be typed 
     // in our own class (MyArrayAdapter) which will be created below
     ArrayAdapter<ProductFromTable> customAdapter = new MyArrayAdapter();

     //get the info from whole table 
     tablecursor = db.getAllColumns();
     if(tablecursor != null)
     {
         startManagingCursor(tablecursor);
         tablecursor.moveToFirst();
     }

    // now we moving all info from tablecursor to ourlist 
     if(tablecursor != null && tablecursor.moveToFirst())
     {
         do{
             // taking info from row in table 
             int id = tablecursor.getInt(sqliteDB.ID_COLUMN);
             String name= tablecursor.getString(sqliteDB.NAME_COLUMN);
             String description= tablecursor.getString(sqliteDB.DESCRIPTION_COLUMN);
             byte[] image= tablecursor.getBlob(3);

             tablefromDB.add(new ProductFromTable(id,name,description,image));
             // moving until we didn't find last row 
         }while(tablecursor.moveToNext());
     }


    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.tagwriter_listoftags);
     //as description says
     // setAdapter = The ListAdapter which is responsible for maintaining 
     //the data backing this list and for producing a view to represent 
     //an item in that data set.
     listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

 }
```

I put the info from row tho objects which are stored in list.

I read tones of question but I can't find any solution for me. Everything works when I put the sample image ( which is stored in app res folder ). Thx for any advice

Logs from logcat:

```
11-13 11:15:54.580: E/CursorWindow(3985): Failed to read row 0, column 0 from a   
CursorWindow which has 0 rows, 4 columns.
11-13 11:15:54.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3985): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-13 11:15:54.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3985): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start 
activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nfc_friend/com.example.nfc_friend.TagWriterMenu}:  
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make 
sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
11-13 11:15:54.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3985):     at   
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
11-13 11:15:54.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3985):     at  
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
11-13 11:15:54.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3985):     at  
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-13 11:15:54.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3985):     at   
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
11-13 11:15:54.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3985):     at   
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-13 11:15:54.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3985):     at  
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-13 11:15:54.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3985):     at  
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-13 11:15:54.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3985):     at  
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 11:15:54.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3985):     at   
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-13 11:15:54.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3985):     at  
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-13 11:15:54.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3985):     at   
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-13 11:15:54.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3985):     at  
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-13 11:15:54.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3985): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:    
Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized   
correctly before accessing data from it.
11-13 11:15:54.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3985):     at   
android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetLong(Native Method)
11-13 11:15:54.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3985):     at  
android.database.CursorWindow.getLong(CursorWindow.java:507)
11-13 11:15:54.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3985):     at  
android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getLong(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:75)
11-13 11:15:54.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3985):     at   
android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:220)
11-13 11:15:54.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3985):     at  
android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToNext(AbstractCursor.java:245)
11-13 11:15:54.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3985):     at   
com.example.nfc_friend.TagWriterMenu.LoadOurLayoutListWithInfo(TagWriterMenu.java:321)
11-13 11:15:54.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3985):     at   
com.example.nfc_friend.TagWriterMenu.onCreate(TagWriterMenu.java:68)
11-13 11:15:54.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3985):     at  
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
11-13 11:15:54.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3985):     at 
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-13 11:15:54.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3985):     at  
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
11-13 11:15:54.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3985):     ... 11 more
```

EDITED 
I add the code which getting all columns, u can see that I use this method to get data from db

```
public Cursor getAllColumns()
{
    String[] columns = {KEY_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_DESCRIPTION, KEY_IMAGE};
    return db.query(DB_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

Comment: Where is log from logcat?

Comment: And what is `IMAGE_DETAILS = "BLOP";`? You meant `"BLOB"` I guess.

Comment: yeah, the logcat is added, and should be "BLOB"

Comment: and I updated the logcat because that was the mistake in my code, if the one letter would be source of this whole problem I would kill myself xD

Comment: so your problem is solved now. Right?

Comment: no, after change to "BLOB" i still get errors, like this pasted to my question (I updated log from logcat)

Comment: I try updated db, unistall and install app and still got this error so it isn't only one mistake

Comment: What is on this line ? LoadOurLayoutListWithInfo(TagWriterMenu.java:321).

Comment: `}while(tablecursor.moveToNext());` - this line

Comment: Instead of adding things right away into the database in `do while` loop, try adding them into an `ArrayList` and then after the loop finishes add them to db.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41177/discussion-between-myway-and-m-wajeeh)